# How to convert the output of MySQLdb's fetchall() to a file stream?

Tags: python, filestream, mysql-python, gnupg

I am writing a python method to dump the entire contents of a MySQL table. However, this table contains personally-identifiable information (PII). I have a requirement that this data must be GPG-encrypted. Additionally the requirement is that none of this data is allowed to be written to disk in unencrypted form (even if that is just a temporary file that is later removed)

I have temporarily solved this problem as follows by using the `subprocess.Popen()` and piping the output of the `mysql` executable directly to the `gpg` executable and then piping that output to stdout:

```
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(
        'mysql -h127.0.0.1 -Dmydbinstance -umyuser -pmyPassword -e "select * from my_table"',
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    p2 = subprocess.Popen(
        "gpg --encrypt -r myemail@gmail.com",
        stdin=p1.stdout,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    p1.stdout.close()
    print p2.communicate()[0]
```

It works, but this seems to me like a terrible hack. It feels very wrong to fork shell processes to do this.

So I want to do this natively in python (without `popen()`). I have a MySQLdb connection to the database. And the `python-gnupg` module can do the encryption on a file stream. But how can I convert the output of MySQLdb's fetchall() to a file stream? So far, all I have is this:

```
import MySQLdb
import gpg

DBConn = MySQLdb.Connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='myuser', passwd='myPassword', db='mydbinstance', port=3306, charset='utf8')
DBConn.autocommit(True)
cur = DBConn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute("select * from my_table")
if cur.rowcount >= 1:
    rows = cur.fetchall()
else
    rows = []
for i in rows:
    print i

# WHAT DO I NEED TO DO HERE TO TURN THE DB OUTPUT INTO A FILE STREAM?

encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt_file(stream, recipient_fingerprint)
```

How can I turn the output of fetchall() to a file stream so that I can send it to `gpg.encrypt_file()` without writing a temporary file to disk that is unencrypted? There could be millions of rows of data. So reading it all into memory at once is not a viable solution.

Comment: why can't you just use `encrypt` instead of `encrypt_file`?

Comment: ah sorry, I get it now. performance reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file-like object similiar to `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` from the [io module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).

Looking at the latest [source code](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/blob/5895997554787ca956c9e0508eb86c3943134a2d/gnupg/gnupg.py#L885) there is no `encrypt_file` anymore, instead `encrypt` [wraps the data in a binary stream](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/blob/5895997554787ca956c9e0508eb86c3943134a2d/gnupg/gnupg.py#L972) using [StringIO or BytesIO depending on the Python Version](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/blob/5895997554787ca956c9e0508eb86c3943134a2d/gnupg/_util.py#L534)

So nothing actually stops you from using `encrypt` directly, if you want more control on how the data is encrypted you can implement a dummy file-object or just write your data to an `io.BytesIO` object.